# Bootstrap carousel doesn't start automatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

It may appear a repeated question but it is a serious one and I found no solution for it in any related question.

I have downloaded a bootstrap theme from ShapeBootstrap website

[Demo theme](http://shapebootstrap.net/demo/html/flat_theme)

I use Firefox 30. As you may see in the demo page too, the slider doesn't start automatically! however if one click on the next slide it starts running!

I did anything I read in the similar questions but nothing happened!

- The order of scripts is OK
- It is in the end of file
- No error reported in console  ...

You can view and follow the source code of the demo page. Everything is in its place. But I wonder why it has this problem even in the official website of the theme.

Please guide me what can I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what was going wrong was difficult!
I replaced the carousal section(html) with this one from http://startbootstrap.com/templates/full-slider/

I added full-slider.css to the list of my css files and used the latest version of bootstrap script and now it works!